# Setting earlier minimum kernel version when compiling static libraries

Tags: gcc, glibc, static-linking, binutils, gnu-toolchain

My distribution (Arch Linux) recently increased the minimum supported Linux kernel version for its toolchain. I am compiling a web application that I link statically and then upload to a web server, and the kernel version on the web server is too old for static libraries compiled with the new toolchain. (I get a segmentation fault when I try to run static binaries on the server.) Is there a way to compile applications using the GNU toolchain (GCC, binutils, glibc) such that features requiring newer kernel versions are left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glibc compatibility is really only guaranteed in one direction.  (Older binaries work on newer systems; vice versa, not necessarily so.)

To guarantee that your binaries work on older systems, compile linking with an older glibc.  The easiest way to do this is to find an older distribution, but I would recommend setting up a "[crosstool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/)" or similar cross-compiling toolchain targeting a different libc than what your build system uses (and this allows for repeatable builds across hosts regardless of what the system is).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I also found the --enable-kernel option to glibc, which enables working with earlier kernels.